# introducing, picking up, or influencing the lifespan of [,] discourse referents (last comma necessary?)

Tags: punctuation

Is this comma (last one of the phrase in the bold) mistakenly left in? I don't think it is needed there because the last element of the parallel structure is 'influencing the lifespan of discourse referents,' or so I think. Is it there so that the readers could easily tell 'discourse referents' is shared by 'introducing,' 'picking up,' and ''influencing the lifespan of'? What do you think?

> Still, it has remained puzzling in many ways just what discourse
>   referents are and where they fit into semantic theory. It seems
>   appropriate to say that we are describing some aspect of the meaning
>   of a word or construction of English when we talk about its capacity
>   for **introducing, picking up, or influencing the lifespan of, discourse
>   referents**. But is that an entirely separate aspect of meaning, or is
>   it dependent upon other aspects of meaning, such as the referential
>   and truth-conditional aspect? --- (page 225 of ['File Change Semantics
>   and the Familiarity Theory of Definiteness'](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/hyper/heim1983.pdf) by Irene Heim)

Comment: It might not be a mistake, but it doesn't seem to be necessary.  She might just have used it to limn her natural cadence. While speaking, some people would pause rather emphatically where she placed the comma, especially if giving a difficult talk on discourse referents.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, whenever there is a list of words (especially verbs in some formulation) there is a definite need for a comma after the final one, prior to the object.

So, a very simple example:  "When the children leave the classroom, they can run, walk, skip, or stroll, around the playground." This makes quite good sense with the final comma.

If it were "When the children leave the classroom, they can run, walk, skip, or stroll around the playground.", it could mean that strolling is the only action allowed on the playground, which is not (usually) the intended meaning.

Comment: That is not true, if the preposition can apply to all verbs, no comma is needed. Conversely,  in OP's example the comma is not needed if the order of the verbs is reversed: "..capacity for  picking up/, influencing the lifespan of/, introducing [*no slash or comma*] discourse referents.

Comment: @frank, in other words, if there was no comma there, it could read equal to *'introducing of, picking up of, influencing the lifespan of discourse referents.' Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Sssamy  Not quite.  First of all, the comma in question is generally considered by style manuals to be inapt:  a verb should not be separated from its object by a comma.  This is a rhetorical device called *hypozeugma* or *adjunction*, in which several phrases (here the three gerunds) are associated with a single, following construction (namely the object "discourse referents").  it means "introducing discourse referents, picking up discourse referents, and influencing the lifespan of discourse referents."

Comment: @frank - fairly sure you're not right here: for all the verbs to apply to "discourse referents", there must be a comma after the last verb, and before "discourse referents" - I don't think there is much room for debate about that.

Comment: @Cargill This is wrong. All the verbs apply to the object "discourse referents," but generally speaking, style manuals do not recommend separating a verb from its object or a preposition from its object. This is a list of three things (gerunds, actually) -- "introducing", "picking", and "influencing". At most two commas are required to separate the items.

Comment: @frank Sorry, you lost me at "delimitate," but I mixed up my referents -- I wanted to talk to Cargill and mistakenly used your name.  I have deleted the offending comment and added a properly-addressed one.  Again, my apologies.  I think we're in violent agreement.

Comment: @deadrat: (1) "When we arrived at the camp, we could see we could do hiking, climbing, backpacking, and swimming in the beautiful bay." and (2)
"When we arrived at the camp, we could see we could do fishing, skiing, boating, and swimming, in the beautiful bay." Seems to me the comma makes a lot of difference - similar to the OP example.

Comment: @Cargill Your example is different from the OP's because the gerunds don't really make sense without their object.  In your example, I think you want to imply that fishing, skiing, and boating take place on say, a close-by unnamed river and only swimming takes place in the bay.  Without the comma, the sentence is thus ambiguous.  But the extra comma won't help you.  It not only misleads your reader into thinking there's an extra member of the list, but it also separates a restrictive phrase from what it modifies.